# Win32 event loop appearing to be the program bottleneck

Tags: python, profiling, pywin32, pyglet

I am making a game in Python with Pyglet. I have just finished the display part, and getting issues with speed. Like a good person, I profiled, and got the following: (uninteresting bits excluded; currently it just redraws the screen when I push an arrow key with random magenta and white)

```
    15085326 function calls (15085306 primitive calls) in 32.166 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   32.168   32.168 <string>:1(<module>)

   120139    0.499    0.000    0.686    0.000 allocation.py:132(alloc)
   120121    0.563    0.000    0.844    0.000 allocation.py:268(dealloc)

       99    0.743    0.008   20.531    0.207 engine.py:58(Update)

   237600    0.796    0.000   11.995    0.000 sprite.py:349(_set_texture)
   120121    0.677    0.000    9.062    0.000 sprite.py:365(_create_vertex_list)
   357721    1.487    0.000    3.478    0.000 sprite.py:377(_update_position)

   420767    0.786    0.000    2.054    0.000 vertexbuffer.py:421(get_region)
   715442    0.859    0.000    1.280    0.000 vertexbuffer.py:467(invalidate)


        1    9.674    9.674   32.168   32.168 win32.py:46(run)
      180    0.007    0.000    1.771    0.010 win32.py:83(_timer_func)


   237600    0.416    0.000   17.069    0.000 window.py:60(SetTile)
   237600    0.646    0.000    2.174    0.000 window.py:72(GetTileTexture)
```

Everything which took < 0.5 seconds for total time has been removed, pretty much. Mostly stuff that couldn't be a problem.

This is the result of me hitting the keyboard for half a minute. For the most part, I could get 2 or 3 changes of screen per second.. I would personally like as fast as I could hit the keyboard. Heck, my aim is a good 50-60fps.

The win32 run being 10 seconds not spent in subfunctions is what worries me. It could be idle time (even though there is a pyglet idle), but wouldn't that be spent drawing?

The part I thought was slow was actually fast; the window SetTile part. To deal with the tiles, I have a 2D list of sprites that represent them on screen and simply alter the images. 
I don't think that's an issue.

The other potential problem I saw was my Update - I have to iterate across ~2400 tiles each time it is called. However, it doesn't seem all that bad. Only 0.7 seconds for 90 keypresses.

I start to wonder if this is a sign that Python is too slow for my needs. Then again, it shouldn't be. It's not too much of a computationally heavy thing I'm doing.

**tl;dr Is the win32 event loop in Python my bottleneck, and what does that mean? If not, where may I have lost speed?**

*Code available if needed. I assume it's Pywin32 used by pyglet.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REVISED Answer:
I deleted the columns that are worthless information, such as self time, call count, and per-call time.
Then I arranged them in descending order by cumtime, and discarded the small ones.

```
cumtime  filename:lineno(function)
 32.168  <string>:1(<module>)
 32.168  win32.py:46(run)
 20.531  engine.py:58(Update)
 17.069  window.py:60(SetTile)
 11.995  sprite.py:349(_set_texture)
  9.062  sprite.py:365(_create_vertex_list)
```

Cumtime means the total amount of time that particular routine was on the call stack.
So naturally some high-level routines were on the stack for all 32 seconds.
Others were on the stack a smaller fraction of the time.
For example, `_set_texture` was active about 1/3 the time, while `_create_vertex_list` was also active about 1/3 of the time.
That suggests vertices are being created a lot, rather than being re-used, so maybe you could save about 30% of time by not recreating them.

But that's just a guess. There is no need to guess.

What you need to know is the fraction of time statements (not just functions)
in *your code* were active on the stack.
You need to know that because if there is a performance problem,
it is such a line of code.

[Here's how the problem can be found if you have one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295799/how-to-improve-performance-of-this-code/4299378#4299378)

The profiler seems based on *gprof*, and [here are some comments about *that*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343).

Comment: Thank you, it certainly helped :D I shall have a look at the stack traces. The other point I feel I was missing was reading tottime instead of cumtime.